# data processing with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

origin data:

```
Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 | Unnamed: 3 | Unnamed: 4 | Unnamed: 5 | Unnamed: 6 | Unnamed: 7
0   NaN        | 202201     | Nan        | 202202     | Nan        | 202203     | Nan       
1   group      | A Count    | B Count    | A Count    | B Count    | A Count    | B Count
2   Part1      | 40         | 30         | 20         | 10         | 5          | 0
3   Part2      | 0          | 5          | 10         | 20         | 30         | 40
```

What I would like is for it to look like

```
    group   |   date    |   A Count     |   B Count
0   part1   |   202201  |   40          |   30
1   part1   |   202202  |   20          |   10
2   part1   |   202203  |   5           |   0
3   part2   |   202201  |   0           |   5
4   part2   |   202202  |   10          |   20
5   part2   |   202203  |   30          |   40
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 1':[np.nan, 'group', 'Part1', 'Part2'],
                  'Unnamed: 2':['202201', 'A Count', '40', '0'],
                  'Unnamed: 3':[np.nan, 'B Count', '30', '5'],
                  'Unnamed: 4':['202202', 'A Count', '20', '10'],
                  'Unnamed: 5':[np.nan, 'B Count', '10', '20'],
                  'Unnamed: 6':['202203', 'A Count', '5', '30'],
                  'Unnamed: 7':[np.nan, 'B Count', '0', '40']})
    
df = df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.drop(index=0, inplace=True)
df['date'] = df[np.nan].fillna(method='ffill')
df.drop(columns=[np.nan], inplace=True)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['date', 'group'],
                          var_name='Group').pivot_table(
        index=['Group', 'date'],
        columns='group',
        values='value').to_records())
    
print(df)
```

I tried this code but got this error

```
c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\main.py:15: FutureWarning: Series.fillna with 'method' is deprecated and will raise in a future version. Use obj.ffill() or obj.bfill() instead.
  df['date'] = df[np.nan].fillna(method='ffill')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1871, in _agg_py_fallback
    res_values = self.grouper.agg_series(ser, alt, preserve_dtype=True)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 850, in agg_series
    result = self._aggregate_series_pure_python(obj, func)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 871, in _aggregate_series_pure_python
    res = func(group)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2377, in <lambda>
    alt=lambda x: Series(x).mean(numeric_only=numeric_only),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 6221, in mean
    return NDFrame.mean(self, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 11978, in mean
    return self._stat_function(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 11935, in _stat_function
    return self._reduce(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 6129, in _reduce
    return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 147, in f
    result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 404, in new_func
    result = func(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, mask=mask, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 720, in nanmean
    the_sum = _ensure_numeric(the_sum)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 1693, in _ensure_numeric
    raise TypeError(f"Could not convert string '{x}' to numeric")
TypeError: Could not convert string '40' to numeric

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    var_name='Group').pivot_table(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 9193, in pivot_table
    return pivot_table(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 99, in pivot_table
    table = __internal_pivot_table(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 169, in __internal_pivot_table
    agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 1442, in aggregate
    result = op.agg()
             ^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 172, in agg
    return self.apply_str()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 586, in apply_str
    return self._apply_str(obj, func, *self.args, **self.kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 669, in _apply_str
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2375, in mean
    result = self._cython_agg_general(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1926, in _cython_agg_general
    new_mgr = data.grouped_reduce(array_func)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1428, in grouped_reduce
    applied = sb.apply(func)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 366, in apply
    result = func(self.values, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1923, in array_func
    result = self._agg_py_fallback(how, values, ndim=data.ndim, alt=alt)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Workspaces\analysis-env\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1875, in _agg_py_fallback
    raise type(err)(msg) from err
TypeError: agg function failed [how->mean,dtype->object]
```

Comment: How are you reading the original data in the first place? From CSV? Looks like you should read it to skip the first line and consider the next two as MultiIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 1':[np.nan, 'group', 'Part1', 'Part2'],
                  'Unnamed: 2':['202201', 'A Count', '40', '0'],
                  'Unnamed: 3':[np.nan, 'B Count', '30', '5'],
                  'Unnamed: 4':['202202', 'A Count', '20', '10'],
                  'Unnamed: 5':[np.nan, 'B Count', '10', '20'],
                  'Unnamed: 6':['202203', 'A Count', '5', '30'],
                  'Unnamed: 7':[np.nan, 'B Count', '0', '40']})
    
df = df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.drop(index=0, inplace=True)
df['date'] = df[np.nan].fillna(method='ffill')
df.drop(columns=[np.nan], inplace=True)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['date', 'group'],
                          var_name='Group').pivot(
        index=['Group', 'date'],
        columns='group',
        values='value').to_records())
    
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Group    date A Count B Count
0  Part1  202201    40.0    30.0
1  Part1  202202    20.0    10.0
2  Part1  202203     5.0     0.0
3  Part2  202201     0.0     5.0
4  Part2  202202    10.0    20.0
5  Part2  202203    30.0    40.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! I tried your solution and get this error message...

`
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: agg function failed [how->mean,dtype->object]
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
`
pandas==2.1.1

Comment: i can`t get you error, please, add many details in your origin data

Comment: I add details error code.

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with a previous code.Can you check my solution in a clear project?

Comment: I already run code in a clear project. what is your pandas version?
my versions
python 3.11.5, pandas==2.1.1, numpy==1.26.1

Comment: I was update my answer, check this